# Given an image in Lua Torch, how can I find its dimensions?

Tags: lua, torch

Let's say I want to know the height and width of `image.lena()`.  What method should I call on it?  A link to a resource for methods on images would be great as the Torch `help` command does not work in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`image.lena()` returns a Torch 3-dimensional tensor where the first dimension is the number of channels (3 for a RGB image), and the last ones are resp. the height (nb. of rows) and width (nb. of columns) of the image.

So all you need to do is use the [`size(dim)`](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/e8155b4/doc/tensor.md#torch.Tensor.size) method as follow:

```
require 'image'

local img = image.lena()
print(torch.typename(img)) -- torch.DoubleTensor

local nchan, height, width = img:size(1), img:size(2), img:size(3)
print('nb. channels: ' .. nchan) -- 3
print('width: ' .. width .. ', height: ' .. height) -- 512, 512
```